# How to move an object continuosly using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-animate

I have a HTML page which has a title. I want to move the title horizontally using jQuery, until I close the browser. How can I do this?

Thanks..

Answer (score 3):

I would use animate

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Kennethxyz/6rkcM/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="title">Title</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div
{
    position: absolute;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
anititle();

function anititle()
{
    $("#title").animate(
        {"right": "+=770px"}, 
        {duration:  5000,
        complete: function()
        {


    $("#title").animate(
        {"right": "-=770px"}, 
        {duration:  5000,
        complete: function()
        {
           anititle(); 
        }});

    }});
}
```

[Source](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Here #title is the ID of the html element holding your title text.

Comment: I am getting java script error and more over I need to move this object until I close the browser.